# Kill all process of bluepill

Tags: ruby, process, bluepill

I have set bluepill process on my live server and after few days I have killed all the commands and removed repo out of the server . Now since long I am getting logs related to bluepill like,

```
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[26961]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/application.rb:36:in `mutex'
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[26961]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/application.rb:137:in `run'
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[26961]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/application.rb:131:in `start_server'
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[26961]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/application.rb:41:in `load'
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[26961]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/dsl.rb:6:in `application'
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[26961]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/applications/no_config/bluepill/config_git/run_emwebsocket.pill:1
Sep 27 23:21:05 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] Going from down => starting
Sep 27 23:21:08 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] pid_file /home/rails/applications/config/tmp/emw_pid.pid does not exist or cannot be read
Sep 27 23:21:08 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] pid_file /home/rails/applications/config/tmp/emw_pid.pid does not exist or cannot be read
Sep 27 23:21:08 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] Going from starting => down
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] pid_file /home/rails/applications/config/tmp/emw_pid.pid does not exist or cannot be read
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] pid_file /home/rails/applications/config/tmp/emw_pid.pid does not exist or cannot be read
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[31026]: [config:ibt_emw_config] Executing start command: ruby server.rb
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - /home/rails/applications/config/tmp/emw_pid.pid
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1033:in `initialize'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1033:in `open'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1033:in `touch'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1027:in `each'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1027:in `touch'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/system.rb:208:in `can_write_pid_file'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/system.rb:68:in `daemonize'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/bluepill-0.0.47/lib/bluepill/process.rb:251:in `start_process'
Sep 27 23:21:09 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb:56:in `send'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/eval_helpers.rb:56:in `evaluate_method'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/callback.rb:191:in `run_methods'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/callback.rb:190:in `each'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/callback.rb:190:in `run_methods'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/callback.rb:159:in `call'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/transition.rb:443:in `after'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/transition.rb:443:in `each'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/transition.rb:443:in `after'
Sep 27 23:21:10 team bluepilld[26962]: [config:ibt_emw_config] /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@config/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/lib/state_machine/transition.rb:441:in `catch'
```

I have tried finding process giving command `ps aux | grep bluepill`

And killed all processes . Will that do the job for me?

I want to remove everything related to bluepill . Should i remove gem ? Will it help in removing background process ?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed this as the rails user (it looks like you did)

You will want to do

`$ sudo bluepill quit`

If that comes up with an error, then you may be running it as the rails user (as indicated by the logs and where rvm is located) in this case as the rails user I would do

`$ bluepill quit`

And then remove the bluepill gem.

`$ gem uninstall bluepill`

Not

`$ sudo gem uninstall bluepill`

I hope that helps.  I may not have enough detail to completely answer this question though.

Comment: I corrected it, was an alias I had, it is definitely uninstall command.